# Postgres, revoke privileges to access some functions in a database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, privileges

To summarize my situation, I have a role AAA that is owner of a db AAA.

I added to this database a lot of functions needed for doing small cleaning tasks in the database, that the users with role AAA don't need to know.

Is there a way to prevent the role AAA from having access to these functions?

With the REVOKE commands it looks like the role AAA is not able to execute or delete the functions, but they can still be accessed.

Solutions?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the database owner from *seeing* functions in a database? Who owns the functions?

Comment: At the moment it's the owner of the database. In the future ideally I would grant all privileges on these functions to a different user role, that should become the owner of the functions, and only them.

Comment: But if they can't see a function, how would that be possible?

Comment: I think that this will depend on whether the database owner is also a database superuser.

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall': it isn't in this case. Just owner of a specific database.